# Issue with Getting Buttons to Show Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

So my original problem was that when I added the Navigation Drawer it made it so my other buttons were unable to be clicked on. I found another thread in StackOverflow which had a similar issue with making their app scroll action stop working. I took the advice and moved the pieces inside the drawer. My buttons are now able to be clicked, however, you cannot see them and the color scheme is messed up. I'm not sure if I have misused the fragments, or I'm missing something that needs to also go inside the drawer XML code. If I could get some pointers of where I went wrong, I really would appreciate it.

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="msse655.regis.edu.ddcharacters.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my fragment_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context="msse655.regis.edu.ddcharacters.MainActivityFragment">

    <ListView
        style="@style/ListofItems"
        android:id="@+id/list_of_characters" />

    <Button
        style="@style/NextScreenButton"
        android:text="Add New Character"
        android:onClick="addCharacter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_of_characters"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <color name="custom_theme_color">#000000</color>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#800020</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#D3D3D3</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>

    <style name="ListofItems">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">380dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentStart">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NextScreenButton">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">12dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

These are where I believe my error is, however, if another part is needed I can upload that as well.

Here is what it's making my application look like:
[image]

And here is the color scheme/layout it should be following and what the other activities still look like (with the addition of the clickable list and button of course).
[image]